Does the set of all support functionals at a point $x\in B_X$ contains a functional which is not a convex combination of its extreme functionals?
Let $X$ be a Banach space. $X^*$ denotes the dual of $X$. Let $x\in X$ be non-zero. Let $J(x)$ be the collection of all support functionals at $x$, defined as:
$$J(x)=\{f\in X^*:\|f\|=1, f(x)=\|x\|\}$$
We know that $J(x)$ is compact in weak-star topology and convex. If possible, give a constructive example of a functional in $J(x)$ which is not a finite convex combination of extreme points of $J(x)$ and also not an infinite convex combination (the same concept with the finite convex combination but here the sum is infinite) of extreme points of $J(x)$.
I was trying to prove that such examples do not exist. It is well-known that $Ext(J(x))$, the set of all extreme points of $J(x)$, is non-empty. Then by applying Krein-Milman Theorem we get
$$J(x)=\overline{\operatorname{conv}}^{weak^*}(Ext(J(x))).$$
Take $f\in J(x)$. Then we can construct a net in $\operatorname{conv}(Ext(J(x)))$ which converges to $f$ with respect to weak-star topology. But could not able to conclude wheather $f$ is either a finite convex combination of extreme points of $J(x)$ or an infinite convex combination of extreme points of $J(x)$. Please help me out. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

What, exactly, do you mean by “infinite convex combination”? For example, if $X = C([0, 1])$, $x$ is the constant function $1$, then $J(x)$ is exactly the collection of all Borel probability measures on $[0, 1]$. Its extreme points are all the Dirac deltas. So would the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$ be considered an “infinite convex combination” of Dirac deltas or not?

If $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure then $\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\delta_{i/n}\to \lambda$ but what I am saying by means of infinite convex combination is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\delta_{1/n}$. But $\lambda$ is not a convex combination (finite or infinite) of the extreme points.

In that case I suppose the Lebesgue measure gives you the answer you want.

Yes.. Got it.. Thank you for your answer hint.. Really appreciated...
